# Text outside group is being cut/clipped

Tags: javascript, angular, canvas, drawing, fabricjs

In fabricjs (v5.3.0) in angular app I have a fabric.Group that contains 12 Rects and a fabric.Text.

```
let group = fabric.Group(rectangles, {});
let text = new fabric.Text('This is very long text that is being cut on zoom', {
      top: -(group.height / 2 + offset),
      originX: 'center',
      originY: 'center',
    });

group.add(text);
```

As you can see text is added after creating a group so the group dimensions/bounds are not changed and this is expected behaviour. Dimensions cannot change otherwise if we will increase group dimension by text dimension, the center point of the group will be in different place (it will affect many other mechanisms that I implemented so I cannot do this)
But when text is long or the canvas zoom is huge the text is being cut horizontally and vertically.
Why it cannot be positioned 'absolute' without any issues?

[text is being cut](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6Kf9.png)

[image]

I tried different font families, setting objectCaching to true/false, manipulating clipPath of the text as well as group but I am not sure if this is the case here.